# Retrieve a char from a std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

Is there a function for getting the char at position `n` from a stringstream without copying to a string first and without removing the char from the buffer? In the documentation I only see a `get` function to retrieve the next char, but no function to access a char at a specific position.

E.g.:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "abcdefg";
char c = s.getCharAt(3); // I am looking for this method
// c should be 'd' now
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `s.seekg(n, std::ios_base::cur)` and read the character at the given position. You can also specify the position using `std::ios_base::beg` or `std::ios_base::end` to position relative to the begin or the end of the stream rather than the current position.